# Google Cloud Patform: How to write a Airflow DAG script to convert a XLSX file stored in GCS to become CSV file?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, export-to-csv, xlsx

I'm trying to export data from xlsx file into Big Query. But as you might know, Big Query doesn't support xlsx file so I'm trying to do csv conversion after the xlsx file is stored in GCS.

I'm trying to do the conversion in an Airflow DAG script using Airflow Operations + Python. If possible, I would like to do it using pandas library only, instead of using third party libraries such as openpyxl.

Appreciate in advance!

Comment: one option is - if you can convert .xlsx to google sheets and bigquery supports data load. see link here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#create_external_tables